# Can't plot pie chart in python(matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

```
def plotPieChart(self, positive, wpositive, spositive, negative, wnegative, snegative, neutral, searchTerm, noOfSearchTerms):
    labels = ['Positive [' + str(positive) + '%]', 'Weakly Positive [' + str(wpositive) + '%]','Strongly Positive [' + str(spositive) + '%]', 'Neutral [' + str(neutral) + '%]',
              'Negative [' + str(negative) + '%]', 'Weakly Negative [' + str(wnegative) + '%]', 'Strongly Negative [' + str(snegative) + '%]']
    sizes = [positive, wpositive, spositive, neutral, negative, wnegative, snegative]
    colors = ['yellowgreen','lightgreen','darkgreen', 'gold', 'red','lightsalmon','darkred']
    patches, texts = plt.pie(sizes, colors=colors, startangle=90)
    plt.legend(patches, labels, loc="best")
    plt.title('How people are reacting on ' + searchTerm + ' by analyzing ' + str(noOfSearchTerms) + ' Tweets.')
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

    plt.plot([3,1,4,1,5], 'ks-', mec='w', mew=5, ms=20)
    mpld3.enable_notebook()
    mpld3.show()
```

---

[image: strong text]

I am trying to create a pie chart from some data that i have gathered from twitter but it is not happening

Comment: Don't use .plot(), use .pie()

Comment: Could you elaborate plss

Comment: Have you done some effort to know how to do a PIE with matplotlib ? just google it ;) https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_features.html